# How to connect to a TightVNC-server on Windows via ssh-tunnel?

Tags: putty, vnc, ssh-tunnel, tightvnc

I need to connect to a particular Windows machine, which is behind firewall, from a remote Unix machine.

To this end I installed the TightVNC-server (2.8.8 GPL) on the Windows machine. It is set to listen on 14900 and configured to "Allow loopback" and *only* loopback connections.

If I attempt to run `telnet 127.0.0.1 14900` on the same Windows machine, it promptly connects and prints out the beginning of the VNC protocol (`RFB...`). So far so good.

Now I use PuTTY to ssh out of the Windows machine into the remote Unix machine. One of the tunnels I set up in the PuTTY session is `R14900:127.0.0.1:14900`.

When I attempt to run `vncviewer 127.0.0.1::14900` on the remote Unix machine, however, it hesitates for a second and then claims: `vncviewer: VNC server closed connection`. If I attempt the same `telnet 127.0.0.1 14900` on the remote Unix machine, it also connects briefly only to be disconnected.

Questions:

1. How does the TightVNC-server distinguish connections to it coming from the same machine vs. those coming via an ssh-tunnel, if in both cases the remote IP of the new connection is 127.0.0.1?
2. How can I overcome this cleverness and let *myself* connect without exposing the Windows machine to the rest of the LAN?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the self-answer indicates that this was a hiccup and no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, never mind -- after restarting the PuTTY session once more, everything began to work...